# recover AJAX post data with Laravel 5.5

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an Ajax script and i have to recover the datas in a controller as POST and we have error 404 ...

**Here is my JS :**

```
function ajax() {
    var values = {
        'str': "Salut",
        'id': "Dave & Alex",
    };
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: '/ajax',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data:values,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        complete: function (result) {
            console.log("complete");
        }
    });
};
```

**Here are my route which is /admin/ajax and which is available to logged in admins:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
        Route::post('/ajax', 'AdminsController@majax');
    });
});
```

**In my Controller i created a method :**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Ajax request']);
    }
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Http request']);
}
```

**I have 2 issues :** 
1. I have an Http request displayed as result
2. How can i display the values of my "values" array ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: explakn the first problem

Comment: my ajax has "post" type but my function returns "get" ...

Comment: Returns get?!!!!

Comment: it returns the value of:     return response()->json(['status'=>'Http request']);
So i see "http request" ... So itdoesn't return what i want

Comment: If you are using route prefixes, I'm quite sure you have to include them in the url route?  So basically, change your route to "admin/ajax" in your AJAX call.